# How to refactor this to be more terse?

Tags: javascript, function, validation, object

So I have a `validatePassword` function that does some validation stuff specific to our project.

Currently, it returns an object, like this:

```
{
  valid: boolean,
  errors: array
}
```

So actual use looks like:

```
const passwordValidation = validatePassword(value)

if (passwordValidation.valid === false) {
  modifiedValidation.password.message = passwordValidation.errors
  modifiedValidation.password.uiState = 'error'
  formIsValid = false
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, where I don't have to instantiate an object as the result of a function and then use it to do things?

Eg something like:

```
if (validatePassword(value).validity === true)
```

But, I don't want to have to rerun the function everytime to access properties of `validatePassword(value)`...

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks rather to the point as it is, if you're doing exactly that. If you are validating several items in a very similar manner, however, you could refactor that part, so that you don't have to repeat yourself.

```
function validate(validationResult, target) {
   if(validationResult.valid === false) {
      target.message = validationResult.errors;
      target.uiState = 'error';
   }
   return validationResult.valid !== false;
}

var formIsValid = [
   validate(validatePassword(value), modifiedValidation.password),
   validate(validateOtherField(otherValue), modifiedValidation.other)
].every(function(x) { return x; });
```